# Custom build rules for visual studio 2005: somehow my build rules are compiling the first file only

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, custom-build

I have 5 .pc files in my project. I've created build rule for them. But every time I bulid the project it is compiling only the first .pc file.
I've also tried to manually compile the 3rd .pc file, but it then still only compiles the 1st .pc file.

Can anyone help me? I don't know what resources anyone will need to solve this. I can provide them if asked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "support file batching" from your custom build file

Comment: I didn't know that files needed to wash behind their ears…